# Why is my 2D Array Maze not printing what is generated?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, cell, maze, system.printing

My aim was to generate a maze made of a 2D Array of Cell objects. Below is the code for both the cell and the maze. Using the debugger I can see that booleans are changing values, and the generation progresses as expected, however when it gets the the printing, there is no path. 
All of the walls are still in place and I can't seem to figure out where the disconnect is,if there is one?

Here is the Cell class:

```
public class Cell {
    //coordinates
    private int x;
    private int y;
    //cell status
    private boolean visited;
    //cell walls status
    private boolean northWall;
    private boolean southWall;
    private boolean eastWall;
    private boolean westWall;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        visited =  false;
        northWall= true;
        southWall= true;
        eastWall = true;
        westWall = true;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public boolean isVisited() {
        return visited;
    }

    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        this.visited = visited;
    }

    public boolean isNorthWall() {
        return northWall;
    }

    public void setNorthWall(boolean northWall) {
        this.northWall = northWall;
    }

    public boolean isSouthWall() {
        return southWall;
    }

    public void setSouthWall(boolean southWall) {
        this.southWall = southWall;
    }

    public boolean isEastWall() {
        return eastWall;
    }

    public void setEastWall(boolean eastWall) {
        this.eastWall = eastWall;
    }

    public boolean isWestWall() {
        return westWall;
    }

    public void setWestWall(boolean westWall) {
        this.westWall = westWall;
    }
```

Here is the Maze class:

```
public class Maze {
private Cell[][] maze;
private int height;
private int width;

//generate the full 2d array of cell objects. all the 'visited's are false and all the walls are true(that's done in the cells constructor).

public Maze(int height, int width) {
    //initialize the number of rows and columns in the maze with the numbers entered
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

    //initialize the 2d maze with the number of spaces allocated by the height and width entered
    maze = new Cell[height][width];
    //fill the maze with cells
    generateMaze();
    //dig a an open path through the maze
    generatePath();
    //print the maze in the console
    printMaze();
}

/**
 * The generateMaze method fills the maze with unvisited, walled cells.
 */
public void generateMaze() {
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The generatePath method digs or generates a random open path through the maze of cells.
 */
private void generatePath() {
    //Find the starting point to start digging.
    Random rand = new Random();
    int row = rand.nextInt(height);
    int col = rand.nextInt(width);

    //starting cell
    maze[row][col].setVisited(true);

    //start digging the path
    dig(row, col);

}

//Depth-First Searching Algorithm that digs in increments of 1
public void dig(int row, int column){
    //generate four random directions
    Integer[] randDirs = generateRandomDirections();
    //examine each direction
    for(int i = 0; i < randDirs.length;i++) {
        switch (randDirs[i]) {
            case 1: //Up
                //whether one cells up is in the maze or not
                if (row - 1 <= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                //whether one cells up has been visited
                if (!maze[row - 1][column].isVisited()) {
                    maze[row - 1][column].setVisited(true);
                    maze[row][column].setNorthWall(false);
                    maze[row - 1][column].setSouthWall(false);
                    dig(row - 1, column);
                }
                break;
            case 2: //Right
                //whether one cells right is in the maze or not
                if (column + 1 >= width - 1) { //alternative: (column + 2 >= width - 1) ??
                    continue;
                }
                //whether one cells right has been visited
                if (!maze[row][column + 1].isVisited()) {
                    maze[row][column + 1].setVisited(true);
                    maze[row][column].setEastWall(false);
                    maze[row][column + 1].setWestWall(false);
                    dig(row, column + 1);
                }
                break;
            case 3: //Down
                //whether one cells down is in the maze or not
                if (row + 1 >= height - 1) {//alternative: (row + 2 >= height - 1) ??
                    continue;
                }
                //whether one cells down has been visited
                if (!maze[row + 1][column].isVisited()) {
                    maze[row + 1][column].setVisited(true);
                    maze[row][column].setSouthWall(false);
                    maze[row + 1][column].setNorthWall(false);
                    dig(row + 1, column);
                }
                break;
            case 4: //Left
                //whether one cells left is in the maze or not
                if (column - 1 <= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                //whether one cells left has been visited
                if (!maze[row][column - 1].isVisited()) {
                    maze[row][column - 1].setVisited(true);
                    maze[row][column].setWestWall(false);
                    maze[row][column - 1].setEastWall(false);
                    dig(row, column - 1);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The generateRandomDirections() class generates an array with random directions 1-4
 * @return Array containing 4 directions in random order
 */
public Integer[] generateRandomDirections() {
    ArrayList<Integer> randoms = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        randoms.add(i + 1);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(randoms);
    return randoms.toArray(new Integer[4]);
}

/**
 * The printMaze() method prints out the maze of cells generated by the GenerateMaze class, to the console.
 */
public void printMaze() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            Cell current = new Cell(i, j);
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            if(current.isWestWall()){
                string.append("|");
            }
            if(current.isSouthWall()) {
                string.append("_");
            }
            else{
                string.append(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(string);
        }
    }
}
```

I always end up with the following output:

```
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, as to what my problem might be. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not printing your maze.

In the `printMaze()` method, you're correctly looping over the maze, but instead of printing out the maze cells, you're creating a new (blank) cell on every iteration.

```
public void printMaze() {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        /* ... */
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            Cell current = new Cell(i, j); // <- HERE
            /* ... */
        }
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

That line should be:

```
Cell current = maze[i][j];
```

Comment: Amazing, now I have a varied output, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of: Cell current = new Cell(i, j);

Try: Cell current = maze[i,j];